# How to equally set the column width in JavaFX table using Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am building a table in Java Fx using Scene Builder. The parent of the table is a Grid Pane. Normally I use computed size to the row's, the column's Min width, Pref Width and Max width to equally adjust the space among the components inside of the grid. And I use Hgrow accordingly to my required use. But the computed size cannot be set to adjust the space between columns in the table as the column would disappear when set. Only a fixed size can be applied to adjust the columns. But space is not evenly adjusted automatically when a fixed size is applied. How do I set computed size to evenly distribute the space in the columns inside the table?

```
 <GridPane style="-fx-background-color: #fff;" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
      <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" />
          </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                 <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                 </rowConstraints>
                    <GridPane.margin>
                       <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                           <children>
                              <TableView fx:id="TB_CourseTable" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                <columns>
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="TC_SchoolID" prefWidth="75.0" text="SCHOOL ID" />
                                  <TableColumn fx:id="TC_ID" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="51.0" text="ID" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="TC_Session" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="103.0" text="SESSION" />
                                  <TableColumn fx:id="TC_CourseCategory" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="COURSE CATEGORY" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="TC_CourseName" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="COURSE NAME" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="TC_Year" prefWidth="75.0" text="YEAR" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="TC_StartDate" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="152.0" text="START DATE" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="TC_EndDate" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="152.0" text="END DATE" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="TC_IsActive" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="117.0" text="IS ACTIVE" />
                                </columns>
                              </TableView>
                           </children>
                        </GridPane>
```

Comment: I would do this in code in your FXMLController. FXML is not very good at configuring components, only laying them out. Have the gridpane columns allow for the resizing then, add the table view in there. Configure the table view in your controller.

Comment: Is there a reason you arent just using a `TableView`?

Comment: Can you post your FXML?

Comment: I am using TableView inside a GridPane.

Comment: I did adjust the GridPane columns but it doesn't effect the TableColumns @DoctorParameter.

Comment: ok sure. I will  add it in the post @Matt

Answer (score 1):

This has all columns equally spaced out when you start setting min and max and pref width it will constrain that column so when you kept adding things there was more and more constraints next time just try and remove all sizing from fxml when your trying to equally space something out java will usually try to default them as equally unless there are constraints on the object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<GridPane style="-fx-background-color: #fff;" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <GridPane.margin>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
    </GridPane.margin>
    <children>
        <TableView fx:id="TB_CourseTable">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="TC_SchoolID" text="SCHOOL ID" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="TC_ID" text="ID" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="TC_Session" text="SESSION" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="TC_CourseCategory" text="COURSE CATEGORY" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="TC_CourseName" text="COURSE NAME" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="TC_Year" text="YEAR" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="TC_StartDate" text="START DATE" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="TC_EndDate" text="END DATE" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="TC_IsActive" text="IS ACTIVE" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```